# Is this the only way to have the functionality of abstract static methods?

Tags: c#, abstract-class, static-methods, abstract

I'm working on a framework right now and the motto is "no redundancy" and "I don't want to know the vendor specifics" so most things are handled through Interfaces and Generic classes. Now I had the situation where I have an abstract class that wants to match things depending on it's own Enum variable ***se*** but it shouldn't have to know how the vendor provides a relatable variable to be matched to ***se***. The vendor could have decided an integer, an Enum or a string would be the best to save that information but honestly I don't want to know.
So I thought well no problem have an abstract static method that must be provided by every implementation of a wrapper to compare se with the vendor specific way of saving that information.

```
//The original version I wanted to be possible
public abstract class AbstractGenericClass<TWrapper<T>, T> where TWrapper : AbstractGenericWrapper<T> {
    protected TWrapper tWrapper;
    //our SomeEnum se is somehow relatable to every T
    //but we don't want to know how
    protected SomeEnum se = ...;

    //called on Start
    public void Start() {
        List<T> ts = FindObjectsOfType<T>;
        foreach (T t in ts) {
            if(T.Compare(t, this.se)) {
                tWrapper = new TWrapper(t);
            }
        }
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractGenericWrapper<T> {
    T _t;

    public AbstractGenericWrapper(T t) {
        _t = t;
    }

    public static abstract bool Compare(T t, SomeEnum someEnum);
}

public class ConcreteNongenericWrapper : AbstractGenericWrapper<VendorSpecificImplementation> {
    public static bool Compare(VendorSpecificImplementation t, SomeEnum someEnum) {
        return t.vendorVariable.toLower().Equals(Enum.GetValues(typeof(someEnum), someEnum));
    }
}

public class OtherConcreteNongenericWrapper : AbstractGenericWrapper<OtherVendorSpecificImplementation> {
    public static bool Compare(OtherVendorSpecificImplementation t, SomeEnum someEnum) {
        return t.otherVendorVariable % 3 == (int) someEnum;
    }
}

public class SomeImplementation {
    public static void main() {
        AbstractGenericClass<ConcreteNongenericWrapper<ConcreteNongeneric>, ConcreteNongeneric> foo 
            = new AbstractGenericClass<ConcreteNongenericWrapper<ConcreteNongeneric>, ConcreteNongeneric>();
        AbstractGenericClass<OtherConcreteNongenericWrapper<OtherConcreteNongeneric>, OtherConcreteNongeneric> bar
            = new AbstractGenericClass<OtherConcreteNongenericWrapper<OtherConcreteNongeneric>, OtherConcreteNongeneric>();

        foo.Start();
        bar.Start();
    }
}
```

---

I found out that that isn't possible and I wanted to know if this version down below is the best/only way of doing it? It has redundancy and I don't like it and it is longer.

```
//An attempt at a solution:
public abstract class AbstractGenericClass<TWrapper<T>, T> where TWrapper : AbstractGenericWrapper<T> {
    protected TWrapper tWrapper;
    //our SomeEnum se is somehow relatable to every T
    //but we don't want to know how
    protected SomeEnum se = ...;

    //called on start
    public abstract void Start();
}

public abstract class AbstractGenericWrapper<T> {
    T _t;

    public AbstractGenericWrapper(T t) {
        _t = t;
    }
}

public class ConcreteNongenericClass : AbstractGenericClass<VendorSpecificImplementation> {
    //called on start
    public override void Start() {
        List<VendorSpecificImplementation> ts = FindObjectsOfType<VendorSpecificImplementation>;
        foreach (VendorSpecificImplementation t in ts) {
            if(t.vendorVariable.toLower().Equals(Enum.GetValues(typeof(someEnum), someEnum))) {
                tWrapper = new ConcreteNongenericWrapper(t);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ConcreteNongenericWrapper : AbstractGenericWrapper<VendorSpecificImplementation> {
}


public class OtherConcreteNongenericClass : AbstractGenericClass<OtherVendorSpecificImplementation> {
    //called on start
    public void Start() {
        List<OtherVendorSpecificImplementation> ts = FindObjectsOfType<OtherVendorSpecificImplementation>;
        foreach (OtherVendorSpecificImplementation t in ts) {
            if(t.otherVendorVariable % 3 == (int) someEnum) {
                tWrapper = new OtherConcreteNongenericWrapper(t);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class OtherConcreteNongenericWrapper : AbstractGenericWrapper<OtherVendorSpecificImplementation> {
}

public class SomeImplementation {
    public static void main() {
        AbstractGenericClass<ConcreteNongenericWrapper<ConcreteNongeneric>, ConcreteNongeneric> foo 
            = new AbstractGenericClass<ConcreteNongenericWrapper<ConcreteNongeneric>, ConcreteNongeneric>();
        AbstractGenericClass<OtherConcreteNongenericWrapper<OtherConcreteNongeneric>, OtherConcreteNongeneric> bar
            = new AbstractGenericClass<OtherConcreteNongenericWrapper<OtherConcreteNongeneric>, OtherConcreteNongeneric>();

        foo.Start();
        bar.Start();
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: You tagged the question with both java and c#.  Which is it?  It can't be both.

Comment: Instead of enforcing inheritance on your TWrapper, enforce on T itself.
Force an interface on T for it to be comparable to your SomeEnum.

Comment: @Lewis_McReu the problem is that T is not written by me but by a third party which means I don't have any influence on it's implementation

Comment: Ok, quick question then: is TWrapper provided by a third party as well?

If that is the case, place an abstract method in your AbstractGenericWrapper that is to be implemented by any third party using your code. This method would then compare T to SomeEnum.
This way you can use it and the third party has no limitations regarding how they implement it.

Comment: @Lewis_McReu TWrapper is written by me ConcreteNongenericWrapper and OtherConcreteNongenericWrapper are example implementations
The thing is I want the method to be static so I can compare before I create an instance